# How to check that a frame of frameset exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a frameset that has 3 frames:

```
 <frameset rows="124, *, 0">
    <frame id="f1" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" src="" name="control">
    <frame id="f2" frameborder="0" src="" name="main">
    <frame id="f3" noresize frameborder="0" name="go">
</frameset>
```

I'm going to check if frame with id = "f2" exist?

I have tried :

```
<script>
if( document.getElementById("f2").contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML !== null) {
alert('ok');
}
</script>
```

But not worked.
I know i should do something like:

```
document.getElementById("f2")
```

but need more info

Comment: What do you mean by "exists"? If the element exists in the dom? If the content of the page loaded?

Comment: I want to prevent html injection by check if id="f2" exist? or deleted by user :) @Dekel

Comment: Frames have been removed from HTML 5. Don't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - actually what you should do is only check if `document.getElementById("f2")` return something, however in order for this to work you must set the doctype of your document to frameset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Otherwise the browser will not recognize the frame, and it will return nothing.

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b8xg9y8u/

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById() returns `null` if the element doesn't exist, so the expression will be false, either add `!` at the begining, or add your code in the `else` case

```
 if (!document.getElementById("f2")) {
}
```

or

```
 if (document.getElementById("f2")) {
} else {

}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("f2") can not access inside frameset.